# RewriteCond Query String condition not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to implement some URL rewrites and I'm running into an issue. The query string condition does not seem to be getting a match.

Example URL:
http://www.domain.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=498688

Here is the rule I have written.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ProductCode=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /catalogsearch/result/?q=%1 [R=301,L]
```

I have another rule that's almost identical that works. Any thoughts on why this one is not firing?